# Creating user-to-item purchase table from users' item purchase table

Tags: r

I am exploring recommendation systems in R and would like to create a user-to-item purchase table.

Suppose I have a data logfile that I can import into an R data frame, where each row contains a (userID, itemPurchasedID) tuple representing that the user purchased a given item. For example:

```
> userID <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4)
> itemPurchasedID <- c(2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3)
> data.frame(userID, itemPurchasedID)
  userID itemPurchasedID
1      1               2
2      1               3
3      3               2
4      5               1
5      3               2
6      4               3
```

I would like to construct the corresponding user-to-item utility table that shows the items that users purchased, where users are the rows and the items are the columns:

```
    1 2 3
1   0 1 1
3   0 2 0
4   0 0 1 
5   1 0 0
```

For example, the above table shows user 3 purchased 2 units of item 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `table` function with the data frame:

```
> d <- data.frame(userID, itemPurchasedID)
> t <- table(d)
> t
      itemPurchasedID
userID 1 2 3
     1 0 1 1
     3 0 2 0
     4 0 0 1
     5 1 0 0
> t["3","2"]
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks. 'table' seems to be quite a powerful function.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(userID, itemPurchasedID)
dcast(df, userID~itemPurchasedID)
```